# Explanation of why "Put this in my Honda" is funny

Tags: phrase-meaning

This was from a video on Twitter I believe and it has been pretty famous recently.
You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRgKsAUQkik).

A guy was commenting and joking about the exhibits and statues and such in the museum. There was a joke where he pointed at a little statue or a figure of a man? and said "ah ah someone put this in my Honda" 
I don't know but this didn't make any sense to me.

Can somebody explain to me what's funny about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a funny because it plays on people's expectations of gay men. The voice seems to be coming from a man. His voice is high pitched and effeminate. This is supposed to suggest that he is gay.

At some point he is in a room. There is some art reclined against a cabinet and he rejects it

> Uh-uh, that looks fake.

He sees some books on the shelf and rejects them

> Ain't nobody gonna read any of them books.

He sees a lamp with a sculpture of the chest, shoulders and arms of a muscular man as the base of the lamp. Like a school girl, the speaker says

> Oo! Ah ah, girl somebody put this in my Honda!

The way he says it is funny, and I believe you are supposed to think

> Of course he'd take that!

This implies that he's not refined since he was only interested in the sexy man.

Other than that, just that way he speaks is funny because he exaggerates how a stereotypical, effeminate gay man speaks.

This is my guess.